# react native android: TypeError: Network request failed

Tags: android, react-native

I'm using fetch command, running on Android emulator. When I used it with port "127.0.0.1" I got this error all the time no matter what type of request I was doing.

Then I changed it to http://10.0.2.2, and GET requests generally work, but I'm trying to make a POST request and get this error:

```
TypeError: Network request failed
```

My code:

```
const url = 'http://10.0.2.2:143'


            const payload = {
                method,
                headers: {
                    Accept: 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    ['x-access-token']: `Bearer ${token}`,
                },
                body,
            }

            const response = await fetch(url, payload)
```

On iOS everything's working fine so I don't think it's a problem with this code. What can I try to make it work on Android

The request doesn't even reach the server

Answer (score -1):

if you are using android 9 or higher you should make requests with https ,  http has   security problems

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to mention that I did try with https and then it didn't work at all (all kind of requests failed)

Comment: oh, check another URL address